# IGBT confusion with determining Ic

Tags: power, igbt

[image]

For this IGBT I-V curve say I have a Vge of 10V and no biasing resistor on the collector with 5 Volts being supplied by some supply providing up to x watts. According to this I-V curve this should be pushing out 550 amps.

Now say I have a Vge of 10V and once again no biasing resistor with the collector being held at a 100V by some supply providing up to x watts. According to this I-V curve this should also be pushing out 550 amps.

Also is it typical to not use biasing resistors to set Vce for IGBTs?
The above should be true as long as my supply is supplying the correct wattage correct? This wattage needed would be the Vce*Ic with the correct voltage and current ratings?  If we 1/2d the wattage available would we just push out less current than the I-V indicates assuming the same Vce? I just want to verify im looking at this the correct way thank you.

Comment: Typically IGBTs are designed for switching applications.  I don't know of any that are designed for linear operation, and while I've used them in linear mode, it was in some bespoke test equipment and was not even considered as a marketable product.

Comment: I must be thinking of how to calculate Vce incorrectly then as all the resources I have use Ic in the equation which is what I am looking for. If I just have a +100V Vcc over the IGBT would the Vce be 100V or is the Vce that determines the current output calculated differently

Comment: If there is a specific circuit that you're puzzled about, please post the schematic. 
 The symbol Vcc is usually the positive *supply*, but in a circuit with a transistor in common-emitter mode, the load (probably a coil or transformer if there's IGBTs involved) would go from Vcc to the collector.  So Vce would be determined by the transistor *and the load*.

Comment: I can't post the schematic but itd be a NPC inverter controlling a motor. I assume the motor inductances would be the load then but that's not between Vcc and the collector though.